# libc-2.3.2.so symbol to libc.so.6

Tags: libc

I compiled a package that includes `binutils`, `linux-headers`, `linux-2.6.9` and `glibc 2.3.2`, `gcc`, etc.

This eventually creates a file bin used to be loaded onto a satellite signal receiver.

When I want to run an external program compiled, I get an error: `relocation error symbol not defined in libc.so.6`.

The symbol is `bcopy`. It´s defined in the static library (`libc.a`) and dynamics also rightful `libc-2.3.2.so`. But how I can do to be included in `libc.so.6`?

Is it possible to export this symbol `libc.so.6`?

Answer (score 0):

> But how I can do to be included in libc.so.6

The `libc.so.6` is (or *should* be) a symlink to `libc-2.3.2.so` that you've built.